# Android Avd running with errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android 4.3 AVD bundle on Ubuntu 12.4 LTS. When I start AVD it shows too many errors.

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_3_7_FWVGA_slider'
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to load libGL.so
error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

How to fix these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replace android emulator with Genymotion. Genymotion is better than android emulator for testing game application [here](http://delyan.me/08-11-2013/the-emulator-is-dead-long-live-the-emulator/)